# Instruction after paging is enabled doesn't appear to execute

Tags: assembly, x86, paging, bootloader, osdev

When I have to setup the EIP register, the program doesn't jump to the correct position. I'm expecting that `jmp *%ecx` jumps at the right spot in memory setting EIP to around 0xC0100000 (label: `StartInHigherHalf`) using LEA. I don't think that `kmain` is necessary because the problem is before it is called. I'm going to post it anyway.

I've tried to debug it with the `-d cpu` flag on QEMU, and before the jump (blocked with HLT) says that ECX is not loaded with the LEA function. Is it possible for LEA instruction not to execute? Why can that happen? How can I fix it?

Boot.S:

```
.set ALIGN,    1<<0                                       
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1                               
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO                         
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002                      
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)            

.set KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE, 0xC0000000                       
.set KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER, (KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE >> 22)

.section .multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM

.section .data
.align 0x1000
BootPageDirectory:

.quad 0x00000083

.rept KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1
.quad 0        
.endr

.quad 0x00000083
.rept 0x400 - KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1
.quad 0                    
.endr

.set STACKSIZE, 0x4000

.global __start__
.set __start__, (setup)
setup: 
    mov $(BootPageDirectory - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE), %ecx
    mov %ecx, %cr3 

    mov %cr4, %ecx
    or $0x00000010, %ecx 
    mov %ecx, %cr4    

    mov %cr0, %ecx
    or $0x80000000, %ecx
    mov %ecx, %cr0

    lea StartInHigherHalf, %ecx
    jmp *%ecx      

StartInHigherHalf:
    movl $0, (BootPageDirectory)
    invlpg (0)

    mov $(stack + STACKSIZE), %esp                 
    push %eax                                        

    push %ebx

    call _init

    call kmain

    cli
1:  hlt
    jmp 1

.section .bss
.align 32

.lcomm stack, STACKSIZE    
.global gdtFlush            
.extern gp               

gdtFlush:
    lgdt (gp)

    mov $0x10, %eax
    mov %eax, %ds               
    mov %eax, %es
    mov %eax, %gs
    mov %eax, %fs
    mov %eax, %ss

    ljmp $0x08, $setcs                              

setcs:
    ret
```

linker.ld:

```
ENTRY(__start__)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0xC0100000;

    .text  ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.text) - 0xC0000000) {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }
    .rodata ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.rodata) - 0xC0000000) {
        *(.rodata*)
    } 
    .data ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.data) - 0xC0000000) {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.bss) - 0xC0000000) {
        _sbss = .;
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
        _ebss = .;
    }
}
```

kmain.c:

```
#include <kernel/tty.h>
#include <kernel/log.h>
#include <kernel/stack-protector.h>
#include <kernel/gdt.h>

__attribute__ ((noreturn));
    void kmain(void) {
    gdtInstall();

    initializeTerminal();
    char c;
    char *buffer = &c;
    char *start = buffer;

    char str[] = "Hello, kernel World!";

    atomicallyLog(1, 1, str, buffer);
    kprintf(start, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `ecx` to still have the value set by LEA, if you're only looking at it after `kmain` returns?  Why not set a breakpoint on the LEA instruction?  This doesn't appear to be a [mcve] of anything, because you don't show the asm for `kmain`, or show any numeric values that you actually saw vs. expected to see.

Comment: if execution reaches the `hlt` / `jmp` loop, then probably `jmp *%ecx` is working as you expect, otherwise you probably wouldn't end up there.  Are you really only looking at `ecx` at that point like you say in the 2nd paragraph?  If so, why don't you use the debugger to look at ECX earlier, before other stuff destroys it?

Comment: ECX arrives at the jump point with a value of 0x80000011 because before I set cr0 with that value. To run QEMU I simply pass "-cdrom MyOSName.iso" and for debugging i pass "-d cpu" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume for a moment that your code actually reaches `lea StartInHigherHalf, %ecx`, and don't think it actually executed this instruction - The most obvious issue would be paging related. The *LEA* instruction happens to be the first instruction to execute after the paging bit is set. If paging is wrong then likely the next instruction will fault.

Reviewing your page directory, I noticed that you build it using `.quad` (8 byte type) instead of `.int` (4-byte type). Each entry in the page directory is 4 bytes, not 8. This likely is the main cause of your problems. You can avoid the `.rept` macro by just using the [`.fill`](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC91) directive:

> ```
> .fill repeat , size , value
> ```
>
> result, size and value are absolute expressions. This emits repeat copies of size bytes. Repeat may be zero or more. Size may be zero or more, but if it is more than 8, then it is deemed to have the value 8, compatible with other people's assemblers. The contents of each repeat bytes is taken from an 8-byte number. The highest order 4 bytes are zero. The lowest order 4 bytes are value rendered in the byte-order of an integer on the computer as is assembling for. Each size bytes in a repetition is taken from the lowest order size bytes of this number. Again, this bizarre behavior is compatible with other people's assemblers.
>
> size and value are optional. If the second comma and value are absent, value is assumed zero. If the first comma and following tokens are absent, size is assumed to be 1.

Your Boot Page Directory could be written as:

```
.align 0x1000
BootPageDirectory:    
.int 0x00000083    
.fill KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1, 4, 0    
.int 0x00000083
.fill 0x400 - KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1, 4, 0
```

`.rept` works as well:

```
.align 0x1000
BootPageDirectory:
.int 0x00000083    
.rept KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1
.int 0
.endr
.int 0x00000083
.rept 0x400 - KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1
.int 0
.endr
```

---

### Other Suggestions

Your code seems to be a variant of the [OSDev Higher Half x86 Bare Bones](https://wiki.osdev.org/Higher_Half_x86_Bare_Bones) kernel. The main difference appears to be that you converted from *NASM* to GNU Assembler. I've written about a major deficiency of this code on the [OSDev Forum](https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=32725). The way it is structured, all the addresses are generated assuming everything is higher half, rather than splitting the lower half that is at 0x100000 from what is in the higher half at 0xC0100000. This design leads to using Mulitboot in a way that isn't really defined by the Multiboot specification.

You can resolve this by using the linker script to separate the two and put appropriate sections in `boot.S`. A linker script (`linker.ld`) could look like:

```
ENTRY(setup)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)

KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE = 0xC0000000;

SECTIONS {
   /* The multiboot data and code will exist in low memory
      starting at 0x100000 */

   . = 0x00100000;

   .lowerhalf ALIGN(0x1000) : {
       *(.lowerhalf.data)
       *(.lowerhalf.text)
   }

   /* The kernel will live at 3GB + 1MB in the virtual
      address space, which will be mapped to 1MB in the
      physical address space. */

   . += KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE;
   .text ALIGN(0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.text) - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE) {
       *(.text)
   }

   .data ALIGN (0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.data) - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE) {
       *(.data)
       *(.rodata*)
   }

   .bss ALIGN (0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.bss) - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE) {
       _sbss = .;
       *(COMMON)
       *(.bss)
       _ebss = .;
   }

   /DISCARD/ : {
       *(.eh_frame);
       *(.comment*);
   }
}
```

Your `boot.S` file could be written like:

```
.set ALIGN,    1<<0
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.set KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE, 0xC0000000
.set KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER, (KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE >> 22)

.section .lowerhalf.data,"aw",@progbits
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM

.align 0x1000
BootPageDirectory:
.int 0x00000083
.fill KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1, 4, 0    
.int 0x00000083
.fill 0x400 - KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1, 4, 0

.set STACKSIZE, 0x4000

.section .lowerhalf.text,"axw",@progbits
.global setup
setup:
    mov $BootPageDirectory, %ecx
    mov %ecx, %cr3

    mov %cr4, %ecx
    or $0x00000010, %ecx
    mov %ecx, %cr4

    mov %cr0, %ecx
    or $0x80000000, %ecx
    mov %ecx, %cr0

    jmp StartInHigherHalf

.section .text
StartInHigherHalf:
    movl $0, (BootPageDirectory)
    invlpg (0)

    mov $(stack + STACKSIZE), %esp
    push %eax

    push %ebx

    #call _init

    call kmain

    cli
1:  hlt
    jmp 1

/*
.global gdtFlush
.extern gp

gdtFlush:
    lgdt (gp)

    mov $0x10, %eax
    mov %eax, %ds
    mov %eax, %es
    mov %eax, %gs
    mov %eax, %fs
    mov %eax, %ss

    ljmp $0x08, $setcs

setcs:
    ret
*/

.section .bss
.align 32

.lcomm stack, STACKSIZE
```

A do nothing kernel (`kernel.c`) could look like:

```
volatile unsigned short int *const video_mem = (unsigned short int *)0xc00b8000;
void kmain(void) {
    /* print MDP in upper left of display using white on magenta */
    video_mem[0] = (0x57 << 8) | 'M';
    video_mem[1] = (0x57 << 8) | 'D';
    video_mem[2] = (0x57 << 8) | 'P';

    while (1) __asm__ ("hlt");
}
```

You can generate an ELF executable with:

```
i686-elf-gcc -c -g -m32 boot.S -o boot.o
i686-elf-gcc -c -g -m32 -O3 kernel.c -o kernel.o -ffreestanding -std=gnu99 \
    -mno-red-zone -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra

i686-elf-gcc -nostdlib -Wl,--build-id=none -T linker.ld boot.o kernel.o -lgcc -o kernel.elf
```

Comments:

- I prefer using a GCC cross compiler, although you can use your native host compiler as well.
- The file `kernel.elf` can be loaded by GRUB (in an ISO file) or directly with *QEMU*'s `-kernel` option.
- I simplified the JMP by jumping to the label `StartInHigherHalf` directly. You can still use the LEA / JMP method but it doesn't gain anything.
- You have mistakenly placed `gdtFlush` in the `.bss` section. It needs to be moved into the `.text` section. I have done so in the code, but I have also commented it out to get this do nothing kernel working with paging. You will need to add it back in to work with your codebase.
- I have temporarily commented out the `call _init` to get this do nothing kernel working. You will need to remove the comment to integrate it into your codebase.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you so much! But now when I want to print to the screen, QEMU reboots... I tried VGA_MEMORY at 0xB8000 and 0xC00B8000 but nothing work

Comment: @MarcoMer Likely because your code has undone the identity mapping of the first 4MB which includes video memory address 0xb8000 . Since you removed it with`movl $0, (BootPageDirectory)
invlpg (0)` you either have to remove those 2 lines to keep the first 4MB identity mapping or you will have to use the higher half address 0xc00b8000 rather than 0xb8000

Comment: @MarcoMer If 0xc00b8000 doesn't work you have something wrong in your printing code or something not quite right in the code I suggested above. You could ask another question regarding that.

Comment: Now I fixed the problem and it worked. Thanks a lot!